# TypeInitializationException C# using mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a web C# app, all tables were created on MSSQL Server, I need to use some data now on another server which uses MySql. I may overcome my problem with a simple web service, but I wanted to add MySql just for learning. Here is the code.

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=10.45..;user id=user;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=db;password=pass");

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from izin", con);
 MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds); **//typeinitializationexception was unhandled by user code**

 GridView1.DataSource = ds;
 GridView1.DataBind();
 con.Close();
 cmd.Dispose();
```

I get

> TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code

error from adapter. I couldn't find any similar problem.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: {"'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager'type starter returned a special value"} I have translated myself, it was in turkish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
You need to add a new user with sql codes. I added mine from menus and it sure doesn't work.

Here is the code.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'some_characters'  
WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```